# Como descobrir o ID dos chats pela API do Telegram?

Tags: php, guzzle, telegram, telegram-bot

Eu estou configurando a API de BOT do Telegram através do Guzzle. Eu estou tentando entender o que seria o parâmetro `chat_id` descrito na documentação do método [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage).

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
   $cli = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => sprintf('https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/', static::TOKEN),
   ]);

   $cli->post('sendMessage', [
      'query' =>  [
          'chat_id' => $ID_DO_CHAT,
          'text' => $this->text, 
          'parse_mode' => 'markdown'
       ]
   ]);
```

O que eu preciso para poder descobrir qual é o ID do chat? 
Eu gostaria que o BOT enviasse mensagens para mim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para descobrir o ID do chat em questão, você precisa acessar o método `getUpdates` da API do telegram.

Usando o próprio Guzzle, ficaria assim:

```
$cli = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => sprintf('https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/', static::TOKEN),
]);

$response = $cli->get('getUpdates');

print_r(json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true));
```

O resultado será simliar a isso:

```
Array
(
    [ok] => 1
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [update_id] => 26020178
                    [message] => Array
                        (
                            [message_id] => 113
                            [from] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 9999999999
                                    [is_bot] => 
                                    [first_name] => Nick
                                    [last_name] => Qualquer
                                    [username] => nickqualquer
                                    [language_code] => pt-br
                                )

                            [chat] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 9999999999
                                    [first_name] => Nick
                                    [last_name] => Qualquer
                                    [username] => nickqualquer
                                    [type] => private
                                )

                            [date] => 1536859308
                            [text] => UM TEXTO DE EXEMPLO
                            [entities] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [offset] => 0
                                            [length] => 43
                                            [type] => url
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

O lugar com o valor `9999999999` é o ID do chat e você deverá usar como parâmetro `chat_id` na chamada de `sendMessage`.

No meu caso, eu deixei o mesmo salvo num arquivo de configuração, já que o valor é constante.

**Observação**: Talvez seja necessário enviar uma mensagem para o BOT do seu usuário, pra você poder ver o ID do chat aparecendo na lista mostrada acima.